# Why is this a infinite lopp?

Tags: infinite

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    char buf[1];
    sprintf(buf,"%i",i);
    printf("%s\n",buf);
}
return 0;
}
```

Is there any reason for i to keep reseting to 0?
this has me really confused.

Comment: `char buf[1];` I don't think 1 is big enough.

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: it is c++ not c.

Comment: maybe its not, but it should not have the effect on the loop it self, should it?

Comment: Well if I make buf[1] into buf[4] it does a proper for loop, but the curiosity still remains of why does it affect the loop if "buf" is to small.

Comment: You are overwriting the value of i on the stack (buffer overflow).

Comment: that makes sense, kinda funny because I knew i was doing exactly that in different problems I had and then i forget it here. Thank you!